# How do you know what resolution a gerber file has?

Tags: gerber

Viewing Geber files in Gc Prevue but don't know how to find out what resolution they are using

Answer (score 9):

You can find the resolution of a Gerber file by looking at the `FS` section.

The `X` and `Y` parts of the `FS` command give the resolution in each axis.

From the canonical [Gerber Specification](https://www.ucamco.com/files/downloads/file/81/the_gerber_file_format_specification.pdf)...

> 4.9.1 Coordinate Format
>
> The coordinate format specifies the number of integer and decimal places in a coordinate number. For example, the
>   “24” format specifies 2 integer and 4 decimal places. The number of
>   decimal places must be 4, 5 or 6.
>
> The resolution of a Gerber file is the distance expressed by the least
>   significant digit of coordinate data. Thus the resolution is the size
>   of grid steps of the coordinates. The unit in which the coordinates
>   are expressed is set by the MO command (see 4.10).

So, the command....

`%FSLAX25Y25*%`

..indicates that the coordinates in the file have 2 integer and 5 decimal positions for both axes.

You can find out the units specified by looking at the `MO` command. It has two possible values....

`%MOIN*%` Dimensions are expressed in inches

`%MOMM*%` Dimensions are expressed in millimeters

So if, for example, the top of a Gerber File had the lines...

```
%FSLAX26Y26*%
%MOMM*%
...
```

...then the file would have nanometer (0.000001 millimeter) resolution in both the X and Y axis because the units are millimeters and the coordinates have 6 digits to the right of the decimal point. (The fact that the coordinates also have 2 digits before the decimal point only effects range, not resolution.)

Note that these parameters only specify the resolution of coordinates in the file. These coordinates are typically connected by interpolated lines and arcs. You can read more in section `4.15 Numerical Accuracy in Image Processing and Visualization` of the spec.

Answer (score 8):

Gerber files don't have a "resolution" as such. They are vector representations - lines, circles, fills. So they can be rendered at whatever resolution is useful at the time - scaled up or down onscreen without pixelating.

For manufacture, the Gerbers have a header which explains the units and precision of all of the points. This ensures that they are manufactured at the correct size. The manufacturer then makes their masks at whatever resolution they require by scaling the vector representation based on the units.

Comment: The coordinates in Gerber Files actually always have infinite _precision_ since they are specified as fixed point numbers. The _resolution_ is limited by the smallest possible increment of those fixed point numbers.